# How to write substr function in active record class of codeigniter model?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a id column in a table with a costant prefix,for eg. NC1,NC2,NC3.....I have to calculate the maximum id from the id column.Here is how i do it in mysql -

```
SELECT max(cast(substr(`column_name`,3) as unsigned)) FROM `table_name`
```

Here is how i tried to do in CodeIgniter

```
$this->db->select_max('cast(substr('column_name',3) as unsigned'),false));
$result=$this->db->get('table_name');
```

It just doesn't work,What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: Did you check the opened and closed bracket in query? it should be  `$this->db->select_max('cast(substr('column_name',3) as unsigned'),false);`

Comment: yea,i was braindead for sometime :)..but i get the following error: - Error Number: 1064  SELECT MAX(cast(substr("ncid",3) as unsigned)) AS cast(substr("ncid",3) as unsigned) FROM (`reelconsumption`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$this->db->select_max('cast(substr(`column_name`,3) as unsigned)','max_id');
$this->db->get('table_name');
```

The second parameter is to rename the resulting field